# How to send a user to a facebook page on the facebook app, if installed?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, ios7

Upon tap of a button, I am trying to send the user to a Facebook page.

I am testing with a random page like this, which exists:
http://facebook.com/WorldwideCollection

Here is how I attempt to launch the page in Facebook app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/WorldwideCollection"];
if ([a canOpenURL:url]) {
    [a openURL:url];
    return;
}
```

Facebook app is logged in and opens. But all I see is my own timeline. It does not direct the user to the page as requested. Is there a different way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **profile** with the Facebook id for the page :

fb://profile/(fbid)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use facebookID of your page to visit like this

```
 //Stackoverflow Page
 fb://page/11239244970
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000316/2458651) link, this was answered on stackoverflow

Especially check these lines of code.

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/****123****"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
```